# Raster time series smoothing package using R

Tags: raster, r, smoothing, time-series

Does somebody knows if exist a package in R specifically for raster time series smoothing?

I´m using aproachs like this one (using the equation suggested by Hamunyella et al., 2013)

```
for (i in 2:(length(stacklist)-1)){
r <-  raster(stacklist[i])
r1 <- raster(stacklist[i-1])
r3 <- raster(stacklist[i+1])
r2<-mean(r1,r3)
r[((r-r1)<(-0.01*r1)) & ((r-r3)<(-0.01*r3))]<-r2[((r-r1)<(-0.01*r1)) & ((r-r3)<(-0.01*r3))]
writeRaster(r,filename=paste(substr(stacklist[i], p1+1, (p1+7)),"_cropmLname.tif",sep=""),format="GTiff",overwrite=TRUE)
}
```

It is fast, But there is not any easiest way? For example for implement another kind of filter, like Savitzky-Golay, Double-Logistic filtering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than looking for a specific package for raster time series you could look for functions for smoothing, and then use these with the `calc` function in the `raster` package. Here is an example for Savitzky-Golay:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843942/smoothen-rasterstack-using-the-savitzky-golay-sgolayfilt-signal-in-r/37846229#37846229

Comment: I´m trying like this:

`fun2 <- function(x) {
  v=as.vector(x)
  z=na.spline(v)
  s1.ts2 = ts(v, start=c(2013,14), end=c(2016,19), frequency=44)
  x=sgolayfilt(s1.ts2)  
}
s1<-calc(rasterstack, fun2)
`
But when I call s1, the follow error appears:

Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
  cannot use this function

What dou think it is happening?

Thank again!

Comment: Follow the (testing) steps in the link I provided. If that does  not work, ask a new question